# undefined local variable or method in own Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods, model

I'm trying create a method in the model called "ingredient_name" but i'm not sure how to define "ingredient" inside of it's own model class.

undefined local variable or method `ingredient' for #

```
 class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    validates :name,  presence: true
    def ingredient_name
        ingredient.try(:name)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please share the name of the fields of your Ingredient model.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
def ingredient_name
    self.try(:name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to alter your method with following:

```
def ingredient_name
    self.name
end
```

As per your provided code, `ingredient_name` method is an instance method. And instance method is finding a field named `ingredient` for your instance.

Comment: Also, I think we can remove `try`, which is not necessary.

Comment: @GaneshNavale "field named `ingredient` for your instance." This statement is written with the intention to explain the author his current working.